# How to load only first n files in pyspark spark.read.csv from a single directory

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

- I have a scenario where I am loading and processing 4TB of data,
  which is about 15000 .csv files in a folder.
- since I have limited resources, I am planning to process them in two
  batches and them union them.
- I am trying to understand if I can load only 50% (or    first n
  number of files in batch1 and the rest in batch 2) using
  spark.read.csv.
- I can not use a regular expression as these files    are generated
  from multiple sources and they are of uneven    number(from some
  sources they are few and from other sources there    are many ). If I
  consider processing files in uneven batches using wild cards or regex
  i may not get optimized performance.
- Is there a way where i can tell the spark.read.csv reader to pick first n files and next I would just mention to load last n-1 files
- I know this can be doneby writing another program. but I would not prefer as I have more than 20000 files and I dont want to iterate over them.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy if you use hadoop API to list files first and then create dataframes based on this list chunks. For example:

```
path = '/path/to/files/'
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
list_status = fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))
paths = [file.getPath().toString() for file in list_status]

df1 = spark.read.csv(paths[:7500])
df2 = spark.read.csv(paths[7500:])
```

Comment: thanks for your help. the above mentioned workks for hadoop. the folder that i have mentioned is actually in s3 location. I will update the problem statement as well.

Comment: The code will work if your files are on s3. You just need to get s3 filesystem instead of default one in the third line.