# Access 200 files in RDD at a time pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

In my notebook folder there are 2000 files, which are named as `part-00000.xml.gz`,`part-00001.xml.gz`,...,`part-02000.xml.gz`

I would like to use `sc.textFile` to generate every 200 of them as a RDD file at a time, and repeat 10 times to get 10 RDD files.

How to write a code in python to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are small in size, I would advise to go with `wholeTextFiles` to load all of the files at once into the RDD.

```
textFilesRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(dirPath)
```

Else, if you want to load n number of chunks into a RDD, it can be done via hadoop API, which is already described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533508/how-to-load-only-first-n-files-in-pyspark-spark-read-csv-from-a-single-directory) answer.

Comment: Thanks. I know the method to load all the files ,but the size of my files are too large, the system always broke and could not produce the answer. So I want to deal with the data separately.

Comment: Ok, then use the link given in the answer and try to follow that. See if you can achieve it.

Comment: That seems does not work for me. When I tried the command `fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs....`an error rises: `module 'spark' has no attribute '_jvm'`